# How to Support Embedded Ruby in Middleman-generated Static Pages

Tags: ruby, server-side, erb, middleman, embedded-ruby

I have a static site generated using the excellent [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/). It has been running happily on an Apache server. I now need to add some embedded Ruby to one of the pages *(Ruby that must be evaluated at runtime, not during Middleman's build phase)*. I won't go into what form this code takes, but for this question please assume that it has to be embedded Ruby.

So what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the .rb or .erb or .haml extensions to any file and it will be rendered first.

for example `blogpost-123.html.markdown.erb` will first have the erb rendered, then it will render markdown, and output as html.